# Error after attempting to train simple LSTM with SPY data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, lstm

I think these errors havev something to do with the format of my data or the way my code is interacting with the data set, but I'm not a developer by any stretch of the imagination so I'm not really sure exactly what is going on.

/Users/kylehammerberg/PycharmProjects/LSTM1P/matplottest.py:54: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
X_test = np.array(X_test)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kylehammerberg/PycharmProjects/LSTM1P/matplottest.py", line 55, in 
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import keras

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khammerberg53/MLPROJ1/main/SP500.csv'
dataset_train = pd.read_csv(url)
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:2].values

dataset_train.head()
print(dataset_train.head())

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(60, 2000):
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=32)

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khammerberg53/MLPROJ1/main/SP500%20test%20setcsv.csv'
dataset_test = pd.read_csv(url)
real_stock_price = dataset_test.iloc[:, 1:2].values

dataset_total = pd.concat((dataset_train['Value'], dataset_test['Value']), axis = 0)
inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - 60:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(3, 100):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i, 0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
predicted_stock_price = model.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)

plt.plot(real_stock_price, color = 'black', label = 'TATA Stock Price')
plt.plot(predicted_stock_price, color = 'green', label = 'Predicted TATA Stock Price')
plt.title('TATA Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('TATA Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print(plt.show())
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khammerberg53/MLPROJ1/main/SP500.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot range from 3 to 100 if you define your `X_test` the way you do. If you change your code to:

```
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(60, 161):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i, 0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
```

the rest of the code will produce (I only took 2 epochs and might explain that the predictions aren't what you expected):

[image]

with 20 epochs, you'd get this:

[image]